# cannot replicate a crash in ios

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, crashlytics

I've got a crash report  from crashlytics  which i am unable to replicate and the crash happens to only a few users( 2 out of 1000 users) I am using ARC and swift  This is the crash log

```
 #0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0 Appname               0x100062540 ageCalculatorVC.calculate() -> () (ageCalculatorVC.swift:127)
1  Appname               0x100063190 specialized ageCalculatorVC.dateChange(AnyObject) -> () (ageCalculatorVC.swift:96)
2  Appname               0x1000615fc @objc ageCalculatorVC.dateChange(AnyObject) -> () (ageCalculatorVC.swift)
3  UIKit                          0x1905230ec -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
4  UIKit                          0x19052306c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
5  UIKit                          0x19050d5e0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440
6  UIKit                          0x190e1b1f0 -[_UIDatePickerView pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:] + 540
7  UIKit                          0x19075e468 -[UIPickerView _sendSelectionChangedForComponent:notify:] + 116
8  UIKit                          0x19075e69c -[UIPickerView _sendSelectionChangedFromTable:notify:] + 340
9  UIKit                          0x190c986b8 -[UIPickerTableView _scrollingFinished] + 188
10 UIKit                          0x190c98890 -[UIPickerTableView scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:] + 28
11 UIKit                          0x19080051c -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewDidEndDeceleratingForDelegate] + 132
12 UIKit                          0x190693188 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollDecelerationNotify:] + 360
13 UIKit                          0x190692c28 -[UIScrollView _smoothScrollWithUpdateTime:] + 2420
14 UIKit                          0x190692230 -[UIScrollView _smoothScrollDisplayLink:] + 560
15 QuartzCore                     0x18d5ce600 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch(unsigned long long) + 44
16 QuartzCore                     0x18d5ce4b0 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 436
17 IOKit                          0x18a62bdd4 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
18 CoreFoundation                 0x18a355958 __CFMachPortPerform + 180
19 CoreFoundation                 0x18a36dadc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
20 CoreFoundation                 0x18a36d27c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
21 CoreFoundation                 0x18a36ad90 __CFRunLoopRun + 1752
22 CoreFoundation                 0x18a29ad94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
23 GraphicsServices               0x18bd04074 GSEventRunModal + 100
24 UIKit                          0x190553130 UIApplicationMain + 208
25 Appname               0x10007c6f0 main (AppDelegate.swift:17)
26 libdyld.dylib                  0x1892a959c start + 4

--
```

This is the function in line 127

```
//MARK: calculate
    func calculate()
    {
        outPutLabel.hidden=true

        if(birthDayTxt.text?.characters.count>0)
        {
             outPutLabel.hidden=false

            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()


            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle

            //birthday
            let Fromdate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(birthDayTxt.text!)

            let Components1 = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Year], fromDate:Fromdate!)

            self.FromDateValue = calendar.dateFromComponents(Components1)!

            //today
            let Components2 = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Year], fromDate:NSDate())

            self.ToValueDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(Components2)!
            print(ToValueDate)



            let diffDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate: FromDateValue!, toDate: ToValueDate!, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

            let str="\(diffDateComponents.year) years, \(diffDateComponents.month) months, \(diffDateComponents.day) days"
            outPutLabel.text=str
            animateLabel(outPutLabel)
        }

    }
```

Is this a memory issue Should i change every IBoutlet with weak to strong that is used in calculate function?

Comment: Which line exactly is line 127?

Comment: line 127 is the beginning of function calculate outPutLabel.hidden=true

Comment: If it's crashing on that line, try adding an assert beforehand, to check that it is set up how you expect. Perhaps `assert(outPutLabel != nil)`.

Comment: @GaryMakin i am having the same issue across multiple functions in the app i am wondering if this is an issue with the iboutlets getting deallocated by ARC before the function was called?

Comment: @GaryMakin The issues are occuring in another Viewcontroller having a function named calculate but does something else entirely Is this because of the same function name in different Viewcontrollers

Comment: Given it's a rare crash, something weird like that is a possibility. So, change your code to be more defensive. Change from a type of `UILabel!` to `UILabel?` and test before you use it.

Comment: @GaryMakin i am unable to run tests when Trying to run Uitests its giving me an error of permission denied Anyway i'll make the changes you've mentioned

Comment: I didn't mean a UI test. Given that this is rare, it is unlikely that you'll encounter the problem. I mean add an if statement testing that the label is not nil.

Comment: @GaryMakin Ok i will check for nil in IBOutlet in functions before executing the functions Thank you